# Apex trigger to insert record in a related custom object based on insert on contact

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql, sfdc

I have a custom object called 'contact relationship' which has lookup to contact and i have added a custom field of type checkbox called 'relationship' in contact.
I want to write a trigger which adds a record in contact relationship every time a record is added in contact if the relationship checkbox value is true.
This is what i have done, but it's not working.

```
trigger ContactRelationshipTrigger on Contact (after insert) {    
    List<Contact_Relationship__c> crl = new List<Contact_Relationship__c>();
    List<Contact> cl = new List<Contact>();
    for(contact con: trigger.new){
        if(con.Relationship__c == true){
            Contact_Relationship__c cr = new Contact_Relationship__c();
            cr.Contact__c=con.Id;
            cr.Name='Rel to--' + con.Name;
            crl.add(cr);
        }       
    }      
    insert crl;
}
```

When i insert a new contact record no contact relationship record is being created.

Comment: Add debugs in for your `crl` List, is it getting populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code looks to be accurate to me, so you should check that your trigger is active.  On the Trigger edit page there is an "**Is Active**" checkbox that you can use to inactivate or activate a trigger.  Make sure that it is checked.

Also the contact name is a compound field so to get the name accurately you need to use

```
 cr.Name='Rel to--' + con.FirstName +' '+ con.LastName;
```

Comment: It is working but the problem is that instead of name i am getting null in the contact relationship object. the problem is in this line :-   cr.Name = 'Rel to--'  +  con.Name ;

Comment: See edited solution, basically it's a compound field so u need to use the individual parts

Comment: No problem, Mark as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

cr.Contact__c=con.name;

from con.name to con.id or just con;

It looks like you just tried to set the name field which contains mohit to a contact object.

Comment: I have edited the question. I did what u suggested still not working.